# Full form of "DSL" in query DSL - elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'll probably be downvoted to death for this one, but I'll try my luck anyways.

I really cannot find any link for the full form of "DSL" of Elastic Search Query DSL, not even on Elastic Search website [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html)!

(Just to keep things interesting, the link (above) talks about another unexplained acronym "AST" - AST of queries!)

Comment: You are not alone!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the context:

- **DSL** stands for *Domain Specific Language*
- **AST** stands for *Abstract Syntax Tree*

See this [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_introducing_the_query_language.html).